# Showing all values in Group By with inclusion of CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following data

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Severity    NVARCHAR(50)
    ,WorkId     INT
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('High',1)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Critical',2)

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN Severity IN ('High','Critical') THEN 'Critical'
        WHEN Severity IN ('Low','Medium') THEN 'Medium'
    END AS 'Severity'
    ,COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
FROM #Test 
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN Severity IN ('High','Critical') THEN 'Critical'
        WHEN Severity IN ('Low','Medium') THEN 'Medium'
    END
```

This results in output -

```
Severity | Total
---------+-------
Critical |   2
```

I am expecting the following output -

```
Severity | Total
---------+-------
Critical |   2
 Medium  |   0
```

I have looked into the following two links which details a similar case but not same and am still unable to get the result -

http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/47705/showing-null-values-as-well-in-group-by-in-sql.html

[How to return empty groups in SQL GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980678/how-to-return-empty-groups-in-sql-group-by-clause)

Any help or links?

### Further update.

Having tried the solution below, the results are still not appearing. Pasting here the actual code wherein I would need to apply the logic

```
SELECT  s.NewSeverity AS 'Severity'
        ,COUNT(WI.microsoft_vsts_common_severity) AS 'Total'
FROM   ( VALUES
            ('Critical','I-High')
            ,('High','I-High')
            ,('Medium','I-Low')
            ,('Low','I-Low')
        )s(OldSeverity,NewSeverity)
       LEFT JOIN DimWorkItem WI (NOLOCK) 
            ON WI.microsoft_vsts_common_severity = s.OldSeverity
       JOIN dbo.DimPerson P 
         ON p.personsk = WI.system_assignedto__personsk 
       JOIN DimTeamProject TP 
         ON WI.TeamProjectSK = TP.ProjectNodeSK 
       JOIN DimIteration Itr (NOLOCK) 
         ON Itr.IterationSK = WI.IterationSK 
       JOIN DimArea Ar (NOLOCK) 
         ON Ar.AreaSK = WI.AreaSK 
WHERE  TP.ProjectNodeName = 'ABC' 
       AND WI.System_WorkItemType = 'Bug' 
       AND WI.Microsoft_VSTS_CMMI_RootCause <> 'Change Request' 
       AND Itr.IterationPath LIKE '%\ABC\R1234\Test\IT%' 
       AND WI.System_State NOT IN ( 'Rejected', 'Closed' ) 
       AND WI.System_RevisedDate = CONVERT(datetime, '9999', 126)            
GROUP BY s.NewSeverity
```

In actual there are only two 'Low' items, hence the output I am getting is I-Low, 2 whereas I want even I-High to appear with 0 count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would go about this is to create your own table of values using a [table value constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
SELECT  OldSeverity, NewSeverity
FROM    (VALUES 
            ('Critical', 'Critical'),
            ('High', 'Critical'),
            ('Medium', 'Medium'),
            ('Low', 'Medium')
        ) s (OldSeverity, NewSeverity);
```

This gives a table you can select from, then left join to your existing table:

```
SELECT  Severity = s.NewSeverity,
        Total = COUNT(t.Severity)
FROM    (VALUES 
            ('Critical', 'Critical'),
            ('High', 'Critical'),
            ('Medium', 'Medium'),
            ('Low', 'Medium')
        ) s (OldSeverity, NewSeverity)
        LEFT JOIN #Test t
            ON t.Severity = s.OldSeverity
GROUP BY s.NewSeverity;
```

This will give the desired results.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30998)**

---

**EDIT**

The problem you have with the way that you are implimenting the query, is that although you have immediately left joined to `DimWorkItem` you then inner join to subsequent tables and refer to columns in `WorkItem` in the where clause, which undoes your left join and turns it back into an inner join. You need to place your whole logic into a subquery, and left join to this:

```
SELECT  s.NewSeverity AS 'Severity'
        ,COUNT(WI.microsoft_vsts_common_severity) AS 'Total'
FROM   ( VALUES
            ('Critical','I-High')
            ,('High','I-High')
            ,('Medium','I-Low')
            ,('Low','I-Low')
        )s(OldSeverity,NewSeverity)
       LEFT JOIN 
       (    SELECT  wi.Severity
            FROM    DimWorkItem WI (NOLOCK) 
                   JOIN dbo.DimPerson P 
                     ON p.personsk = WI.system_assignedto__personsk 
                   JOIN DimTeamProject TP 
                     ON WI.TeamProjectSK = TP.ProjectNodeSK 
                   JOIN DimIteration Itr (NOLOCK) 
                     ON Itr.IterationSK = WI.IterationSK 
                   JOIN DimArea Ar (NOLOCK) 
                     ON Ar.AreaSK = WI.AreaSK 
            WHERE  TP.ProjectNodeName = 'ABC' 
                   AND WI.System_WorkItemType = 'Bug' 
                   AND WI.Microsoft_VSTS_CMMI_RootCause <> 'Change Request' 
                   AND Itr.IterationPath LIKE '%\ABC\R1234\Test\IT%' 
                   AND WI.System_State NOT IN ( 'Rejected', 'Closed' ) 
                   AND WI.System_RevisedDate = CONVERT(datetime, '9999', 126)         
        ) WI
            ON WI.Severity = s.OldSeverity   
GROUP BY s.NewSeverity;
```

Comment: Tried this but am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks a lot and it also helped me to understand solution better.