# How to merge 2 columns with all possible combinations in SQL?

Tags: sql, merge, combinations, ansi-sql

The question sounds confusing, but just look:

This way we can get the first column (*col1*):

```
select distinct maker
from product
```

And the second column (*col2*):

```
select distinct type,maker
from product
```

So now I need to get all possibly combinations from col1  and col2. Any suggestion?

Shortly, this:

```
A f1

B f2
```

Should become this:

```
A f1

A f2

B f1

B f2
```

P.S.  This query won't return that I need.

```
select distinct A.maker, B.type
from product as A
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cross join` to get all combinations:

```
select m.maker, t.type
from (select distinct maker from product) m cross join
     (select distinct type from product) t;
```

This is ANSI SQL syntax and should be supported in any database.

Answer (score 1):

variant using `cross join` but without subqueries will give same result as in `@Gordon Linoff` post, so you will get all possible combinations

```
select distinct A.maker, B.type
from product as A cross join product as B
```