# Return 0 in GROUP BY when COUNT(*) is NULL

Tags: sql, count, null, group-by, intersystems-cache

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT
    CAST(IndexedDate as varchar),
    COUNT(*) AS Logins
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    EventType = 'Login'
AND IndexedDate > DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    IndexedDate
ORDER BY
    IndexedDate DESC
```

This would leave gaps, for example:

> ```
> 2016-09-13    41
> 2016-09-12    31
> 2016-09-09    15
> 2016-09-08    36
> ```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980678/how-to-return-empty-groups-in-sql-group-by-clause), I tried the following and still received the gaps but on top of that the results were wrong (the numbers were MUCH higher):

```
SELECT
    CAST(IndexedDate as varchar),
    SUM(Case When COUNT(*) Is Null Then 0 Else COUNT(*)  End) AS Logins
FROM
...
```

How can I get my results to look like this?

> ```
> 2016-09-13    41
> 2016-09-12    31
> 2016-09-11    0
> 2016-09-10    0
> 2016-09-09    15
> 2016-09-08    36
> ```

I've checked a few other questions but they all involve joins or other factors not in my scenario.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on comments, I've attempted an `OUTER JOIN`.  This iteration finally ran successfully, but the results were a bit backwards...

```
SELECT
        CAST(a.IndexedDate as varchar) as dt,
        COUNT(*) AS Logins
FROM 
        (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table
        WHERE IndexedDate > DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
        AND EventType = 'Login'
        ) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT(IndexedDate)
        FROM Table
        WHERE IndexedDate > DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
        ) b
ON 
        a.IndexedDate = b.IndexedDate
GROUP BY
        b.IndexedDate
ORDER BY
        b.IndexedDate DESC
```

Results:

> ```
> 2016-09-13    41
> 2016-09-12    31
> (null)    1
> (null)    1
> 2016-09-09    15
> 2016-09-08    36
> ```

I verified that aggregate `b` includes the missing dates.

Comment: Outer join with a calendar table (holding all possible dates).

Comment: ahhh, makes sense. I was hoping for an easier way but I guess you can't get something from nothing.

Comment: Second  @jarlh's answer.  This is really the only reasonable way to do what you want to do.

Comment: To follow on the comment by @jarlh , SQL queries are great for taking existing information and transforming it it into something you want.  But in your case, if date data really be missing, then calendar tables are a good way to bring that data in.

Comment: You actually create a list of dates on the fly using a technique like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141507/how-to-generate-a-range-of-dates-in-sql-server in SQL Server. That table `n` can be joined with your table on date to get count(*) where needed.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE instead of a date table.

Comment: Well, I'm giving it a go, but the query is already taking longer than it should... I'll keep playing with it and if nobody has posted an actual answer I'll post when I get it working.

Comment: Rolled back tag change as the DBMS is *always* relevant...

Comment: @KamilG.: it makes a **big** difference which DBMS is being used (and if you think it doesn't, you shouldn't have added the `sql-server` tag)

Comment: This was my mistake, I stand corrected, sorry for the fuzz.

Comment: Caché isn't what you'd call popular, no worries.

Comment: Well I tried my hand at an `OUTER JOIN` with limited luck.  Please see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I flipped the aggregates from the edit to my original post and now it's  working:

**Query**

```
SELECT
        CAST(a.IndexedDate as varchar) as dt,
        COUNT(EventType) AS Logins
FROM 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT(IndexedDate)
        FROM Table
        WHERE IndexedDate > DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
        ) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table
        WHERE IndexedDate > DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
        AND EventType = 'Login'
        ) b
ON 
        a.IndexedDate = b.IndexedDate
GROUP BY
        a.IndexedDate
ORDER BY
        a.IndexedDate DESC
```

**Results**

> ```
> 2016-09-13    41
> 2016-09-12    31
> 2016-09-11    0
> 2016-09-10    0
> 2016-09-09    15
> 2016-09-08    36
> ```

Note that I had to replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(EventType)` so it wouldn't count the date from the aggregate which was resulting in a 1.

Comment: No, the `1` comes from the fact that when you `full outer join` to b, every row in b will have a row in your resultset, meaning the *count of rows* for that date will really be 1, even if you don't have any data from table `a` for that row.  You need to replace your `count(*)` expression in your `select` with `case when a.IndexedDate is null then 0 else count(*) end` to correctly assign a `0` for those rows.

Comment: I was about 10 seconds ahead of you!  Thanks though!

Comment: Scott do you have an Event for each IndexedDate, even if it is not a Login EventType?  If you had no events on a given day in your table, wouldn't this omit that date?

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned in the original question I did validate that all the dates are there, plus this table is MASSIVE and there are tens of thousands of logged events per day.  If a date is missing, there's something terribly wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

This works (in SQL Server)

```
declare @mindt date = (select min(IndexedDate ) from p);
declare @dtrange int = DATEDIFF(day,@mindt,(select max(IndexedDate ) from p));

with MyCte AS
    (select   MyCounter = 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT   MyCounter + 1
     FROM     MyCte
     where    MyCounter < @dtrange)
select coalesce(IndexedDate , dateadd(d, mycounter, @mindt)) IndexedDate
, count(IndexedDate)
from   MyCte 
left join p
  on dateadd(d,mycounter,@mindt) = p.IndexedDate 
group by coalesce(IndexedDate , dateadd(d, mycounter, @mindt))
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

We basically need two main figures, the starting date and the date range.

The we build a quick counter for the number of days in the date range.

Then we select each slot in the date range and assign a date and a value, if there are none we create a date with `DateAdd` and assign 0 as the value.

[Here is a functional](http://rextester.com/BBQRDA48270) example