# Want to return 0 in case of no rows

Tags: sql

```
select 
    IMEI_ID, dev_status, nvl(count(1), 0) AS Count
from 
    device
where 
    IMEI_ID IN (284700, 250779, 320700, 339622, 323400)
    and Dev_status = 'ACTIVE'
group by 
    IMEI_ID,dev_status;
```

For a few `IMEI_ID`, no rows are returned. I want the count to be Zero (0) for these missing rows.

Thanks

Comment: Which's sql type?

Comment: Not sure what `nvl` is in your script, you can try `coalesce(count(1),0)`

Comment: please mention the sql dialect or the database product you are using

Comment: You need a on-the-fly constructed table of `IMEI_ID`s this is sql product specific (`nvl` -  Oracle i guess?). Then left join your query.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532916/return-0-in-group-by-when-count-is-null

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle

```
with i(ime_id) as
( 
    SELECT 284700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 250779 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 320700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 339622 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 323400 FROM DUAL 
)
select i.IMEI_ID, d.dev_status, nvl(count(d.ime_id),0) AS Count
from i
left join device d on i.ime_id = d.IMEI_ID
   and d.Dev_status='ACTIVE'
group by i.IMEI_ID, d.dev_status;
```

Comment: And the modern MySQL and MariaDB versions which also support CTE and tableless selects with DUAL dummy table

Comment: @RaymondNijland,  'nvl` in OP points to Oracle, so I didn't mention other dbmses.

Comment: true `nvl()` is Oracle only but it can be replaced with `coalesce()` to support other dbmses as well..

Answer (score 0):

Create a (temporary) table with the requested `IMEI_ID` and then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the device:

```
SELECT          imei_ids.imei_id,
                device.dev_status,
                COUNT(device.dev_status)
FROM            imei_ids
LEFT OUTER JOIN device
             ON imei_ids.imei_id = device.imei_id
            AND device.dev_status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY        imei_ids.imei_id,
                device.dev_status;
```