# group by multiple columns having count 0 for all

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I have a query where it has to return count of 0, if no records found on group by. but i am getting empty results.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, s.CreatedAt) AS 'Year',DATEPART(MONTH, s.CreatedAt) AS 
'Month', count(*) AS 'count'
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.Id IN (
SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE Id IN (
SELECT id FROM table4 WHERE Gradingresult LIKE '%abcd%'
GROUP BY id
)) AND t1.column1 LIKE 'hello' AND t1.column2='world' AND t2.column1 != 
'somestring' 
AND t1.CreatedAt BETWEEN  DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, t1.CreatedAt), DATEPART(MONTH, t1.CreatedAt)
```

i want it to be displayed like below,

```
    year month      count
    2019    2         0
    2019    4         0
    2018    7         0
```

but i am getting result as below

```
    year   month    count
```

nothing here, no rows.

i have tried different ways like case statement, isnull(), left join and others but not able to get desired result

editing
i have considered year as well
updated actual query i have, if i don't included **t2.column1** condition i am getting below results

```
    year  month   count
    2019  5        10
    2019  4        25
    2019  2         9
    2018  10       19
```

if i include above specified condition i should get desired result

Comment: Have a help table (or recursive cte) returning 1 - 12. outer join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return empty groups in SQL GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980678/how-to-return-empty-groups-in-sql-group-by-clause)

Comment: @jarlh, with cte, i am able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no rows in the table, there are no rows in the result set.  You can use a `left join` to get the rows you want:

```
select v.mon, count(t.createdat)
from (values (2), (4), (7)) v(mon) left join
     tableT t
     on month(t.createdat) = v.mon
group by v.mon
order by v.mon;
```

You need to be *very careful* with this formulation, because you have not included the year.  When working with months, you should usually be considering the year as well.

Comment: i am considering year as well, but i didn't specify in question, but still getting empty result

Comment: @JyothiPrakash . . . This *cannot* return an empty result with a `left join`.

Comment: thank you it worked after doing some modification based on your suggestion